# How to implement API into angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, callback

Well, I know that javascript is asynchronize. So if I write my code as below, and then I call it in controller I will got '[]' as a result.

But I the http get request to finish it process before doing anything else. Or my ionic apps will breakdown. So How could I do this?

```
var starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']); 

starter.factory('AllEvent', function($http) {
  var allEvent = [];
  $http.get('/api/event/new').success(function(data) {
    var allEvent = {
      all: function() {
        return data;
      },
      remove: function(Event) {
        $data.splice(data.indexOf(Event), 1);
      },
      get: function(_id) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i]._id === _id) {
          return data[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
      }
    };
  });
  return allEvent;
});
```

P.S. this code is a modified code from tabs template in ionic.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use the same variable as an Array and an object ?

```
var starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

starter.factory('AllEvent', function($http) {
    return {
        getNew : function(){
            return $http.get('/api/event/new').success(function(data) {
                return {
                    all: function() {
                        return data;
                    },
                    remove: function(Event) {
                        $data.splice(data.indexOf(Event), 1);
                    },
                    get: function(_id) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            if (data[i]._id === _id) {
                                return data[i];
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In the Controller

```
AllEvent.getNew().then(function(eventObj){
   eventObj.all();
})
```

Hope this works ..